# LINQ GroupBy error: Operator && cannot be used on operands of type 'string' and 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, group-by

**Goal**: Group by 2 columns

**Error**:Operator && cannot be used on operands of type 'string' and 'string'

I've tried changing the && the + according to another SO I read. This did not work either.

**Code**:

```
return db.View.Where(m => m.Mem_ID == Some_MemID && m.Last_Name.ToLower() == Search_MemLastName.ToLower()).GroupBy(t => t.Sub_ID && t.Mem_Seq).OrderBy(s => s.Sub_ID);
```

Comment: `.GroupBy(t => new { t.Sub_ID, t.Mem_Seq })`

Comment: Also keep in mind that you are ordering by group key, so to sort your collection use `s => s.Key.Sub_ID`

Comment: @JeffMercado this did not work, it caused the error IGrouping<anonymous type:Sub_ID, string Mem_Seq> does not contain a definition for 'Sub_ID' and no extension ethod 'SubID' accepting a first argument of type IGrouping<anonymous type:Sub_ID, string Mem_Seq>

Comment: No it works, just your sorting approach doesn't work anymore since you're dealing with groupings now... Aleks's comment should address that...

Comment: @AleksAndreev that gives the error: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<<>> to System.Linq.IQueryable<>

Comment: Before you proceed any further, I suggest you stop and understand what the meaning of those errors are and figure out what exactly do you want from this query and the method you are in. Your return type probably needs to change too and we can tell you what needs to change to remove that next error but it won't help if you have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in your `GroupBy()`

```
GroupBy(t => t.Sub_ID && t.Mem_Seq)
```

If you want to GroupBy multiple properties you can do it like this:

```
GroupBy(t => new {t.Sub_ID, t.Mem_Seq})
```

Comment: This causes the error IGrouping<anonymous type:Sub_ID, string Mem_Seq> does not contain a definition for 'Sub_ID' and no extension ethod 'SubID' accepting a first argument of type IGrouping<anonymous type:Sub_ID, string Mem_Seq>